# Run the helper function by command in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am creating a command and a helper function in laravel.

In `app/Helper/Function.php`

```
<?php

    namespace App\Helper;
    
    class Function
    {
       static public function testCommand()
       {
          return "success";
       }
    }
```

In `Console/Commands/TestCommand.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test:command';

    protected $description = 'Test Command';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
      // call the helper's testCommand function here
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the `testCommand()` function on function `handle()` to process

And when I run: : `php artisan test:command` then it will get the result of the function :`testCommand()` . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use App\Helper\Function;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test:command';

    protected $description = 'Test Command';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
      $test = Function:: testCommand();
      return $test;
    }
}
```